# Having trouble understanding how to disprove/prove if a formula is a function.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, real-numbers

Is $\frac 1{x^2-2}
$ a function from $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$? Is it a function from $\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{R}$?
I have been thinking about this but, I can't find any example for which you can have an input that outputs something that is either not a real number, or where there is 2 outputs for 1 input.

So I assume both examples that this formula is a function, but I feel that is not right, nor would I know how to explain my logic.

Also would $\frac10$ be part of the set of real numbers?

Comment: What do you mean by 1/0?  Can you explain?

Comment: @Mnifldz 1/0 would be the output if you input square root of 2, which this formula would be undefined at that value. I don't know if the phrase undefined is part of a set or if its considered or anything.

Comment: My answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1525054/why-are-removable-discontinuities-even-discontinuities-at-all/1525083#1525083) may be of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of how you want to think of this is on what domain is the function defined.  We see that there are asymptotes when $x = \pm \sqrt{2}$, but this means that the function is not actually defined at these points, hence it is not a function from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.  On what domain is the function defined on then?  Does this domain include $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Yes it should be defined on the set integers your answer makes sense

Comment: @Jude But the function is defined on a domain larger than $\mathbb{Z}$.  Can you tell what domain this is?

Comment: this formula would be a function if we said from R->R where x cannot = $\sqrt2$

Comment: @Jude Correct.  There are a couple ways to write this.  We can say $\mathbb{R}/\{\pm\sqrt{2}\} \to \mathbb{R}$ or more formally $(\mathbb{R} - \{-\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}\}) \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Ah okay, that makes a lot of sense when it comes to understanding thanks

Comment: @Jude Of course, I'm glad to help.  I do want to make one suggestion though.  In the future when posting questions and answers I'd highly recommend getting comfortable with the typesetting norms on this site.  There is a [nifty reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) you can check out for details on how to do this.  You can also click to see the edits I made to your post to get an idea of how to do things.

Comment: alrighty will do

Comment: @Mnifldz I assume you mean $\mathbb{R}\backslash\{\pm\sqrt{2}\}$, not what you wrote.

Comment: @B.Pasternak I have seen both notations in practice.  What's important is that one understands in context what is happening.

Comment: @Mnifldz I have never seen the notation you use for leaving elements out of a set, only for denoting a group action. I also think that using that notation for leaving elements out of a set as the symbol is reminiscent of division, which is not at all what you are doing, but which is a way of viewing quotienting out by for example a subgroup.