# Illusionary singularities in functions

Tags: paradoxes, singularity

If given the function $$f(x) = \frac{-x^3 + 1}{x^2 - 1}$$ one can clearly see that it is not defined when $x = \pm1$.

We can rewrite the equation by factoring out $(x-1)$ in both the numerator and the denominator $$f(x) = \frac{-(x-1)(x^2+x+1)}{(x+1)(x-1)} = - \frac{x^2 +x + 1}{x+1}$$

Now $f(x)$ is defined for $x = 1$. Why? How can this be? How can a function change properties when simplifying it? Is it only the most simple version of a function that defines its properties? Please help me understand.

Comment: This apparent issue is readily dismissed if you factor in the concept of quantification. Do you know about quantifiers?

Comment: Pedants and teachers get excited about the function being *different* after factoring out the $x-1$. But for all practical purposes it is the same. If a function has a *removable* discontinuity (ie if you can define it to have a value equal to the limit there and get a continuous function), then most people just regard it as having that value. There is no good reason for not taking $f(1)$ to be $-\frac{3}{2}$.

Comment: I'm afraid that the OP may not know what the word "(dis)continuity" mean. OP: If you draw graphs of both functions, they will be the same graphs *except* of one point ($x=1$). You are advised to count graphs differing in a finite number of points (this time just one point) as if they would be the same

Comment: You can only factor out non-zero terms.  (x-1) is not non-zero at (x-1) so you can *not* factor out (x-1) at x=1.  The function resulting is a different function entirely and is *not* merely a "simplification".

Comment: There are mainly three types of singularities, cf. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolated_singularity

Comment: This question appears to be a duplicate of ["Why are removable discontinuities even discontinuities at all?"](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1525054/why-are-removable-discontinuities-even-discontinuities-at-all/1525083#1525083).

Answer (score 1):

When dividing both numerator and denominator with $x-1$ you get a **different** function. This is because you can divide the numerator and denominator with $x-1$ **only** if $x-1\ne 0$. These functions are the same when $x-1\ne 0$, but there is **no** reason to assume that the functions will be the same at $x=1$. In fact one these two functions is not defined at all at $x=1$.

Comment: this is the real analysis point of view. in complex analysis, it is more subttle, in most cases it is more convenient to consider analytic continuation of functions instead

Answer (score 1):

The two expressions are equivalent *everywhere they are both defined*.

For a simpler example, consider the expressions "$\frac xx$" and "$1$". They're the same, right? Nope. They are the same for all nonzero $x$.