# $\sin{2x} = \frac{2 \tan {x}}{1 + \tan^2{x}}$. Do L.H.S. and R.H.S. have same domain?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I can see that in the function $\sin{2x}$, x can be any real number.

But I can also see that in the function $\frac{2 \tan {x}}{1 + \tan^2{x}}$, x cannot  be $n \pi + \frac{\pi}{2}$ where n = any integer.

But both functions are equal. How can two functions which are equal have different domains ?

Comment: It is understood that the identity applies only for $x$ such that both sides are defined, i.e., $x$ in the intersection of the domains of the two functions.

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1525054/why-are-removable-discontinuities-even-discontinuities-at-all) answer your question?

Comment: If $ x=\pi/2+n\pi $, you cannot speak about the second function at all.

Comment: [@GeoffreyTrang](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/684071/geoffrey-trang) $$\frac{2\tan x}{1+\tan^2x}=\frac{2\tan x}{\sec^2x}=2\tan x\cos^2x=2\sin x\cos x=\sin2x$$

Comment: @Andrew Chin I read the answer, but I still cannot understand how L.H.S and R.H.S functions are equal if L.H.S is defined for all real numbers, but R.H.S is not defined for all real numbers, i.e. their domains are unequal.

Comment: @AndrewChin Yes, indeed.

Comment: If their domains are unequal, then they are unequal functions.

Comment: @Andrew Chin If $x = \frac{π}{2}$, $\sin{2x} $ is defined but $ \frac{2\tan{x}}{1 + \tan^2{x}}$ is not defined. So, does $\frac{π}{2}$ belongs to the domain of $\sin{2x}$ here ?

Comment: You are correct.