# How to know if I have changed the graph of a function or not?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

**Case 1:**

$$\frac{2x^2}{4x^3}$$

$$\frac{1}{2x}$$

The [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/q1itbvwtwd) hasn't changed.

**Case 2:**

$$\frac{6t^4+4t^2}{t}$$

$$6t^3+4t$$

The [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dkmmrt2g88) hasn't changed.

**Case 3:**

$$\frac{x^3-8}{x^2-4}$$

$$\frac{(x-2)(x^2+2x+4)}{(x+2)(x-2)}$$

$$\frac{(x^2+2x+4)}{(x+2)}$$

The [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fqge13azyf) hasn't changed.

**Question(s):**

1. How will I know that the graph will be the same after my operations?
2. What things should I always avoid if I want to keep the function/graph the same?

Comment: $\dfrac 1t$ is not defined when $t=0$

Comment: $x^3-8 \ne \left(x-2\right)\left(x+2\right)^2 $

Comment: The graph has clearly changed in both cases 2 and 3; there is a hole discontinuity in one graph but not the other (or it is in a different place).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For case $1$ we have that the two expressions are indeed equivalent since they are defined in both cases for $x\neq 0$.

For case $2$ the function are different because the first expression is not defined at $t=0$.

For case $3$ the function are different because the first expression is not defined at $x=2$.

More in general for $b(x_0)\neq 0$

$$f(x)=\frac{(x-x_0)a(x)}{(x-x_0)b(x)} \quad g(x)=\frac{a(x)}{b(x)}$$

have the same graph on all the domain of definition but $f(x)$ is not defined at $x=x_0$. The two expressions are equivalent if also $g(x)$ is not defined at $x=x_0$.

Refer also to the related

- [Why are removable discontinuities even discontinuities at all?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1525054/505767)