# How do these two different functions have the same derivative?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

$$\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{6x^4+4x^2}{x})=18x^2+4\tag{1}$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}(6x^3+4x)=18x^2+4\tag{2}$$

According to this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4272536/768162), (1) & (2) are different functions (see case 2). [(1)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i2d=true&i=D%5B%5C%2891%29%5Cfrac%5C%28123%296Power%5Bx%2C4%5D%2B4Power%5Bx%2C2%5D%5C%28125%29%5C%28123%29x%5C%28125%29%5C%2893%29%2Cx%5D) & [(2)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i2d=true&i=D%5B%5C%2891%29%5C%28123%296Power%5Bx%2C3%5D%2B4x%5C%28125%29%5C%2893%29%2Cx%5D) have the same derivative. How can two different functions have the same derivative?

Comment: Because your first computation is incomplete, the RHS is not quite right.

Comment: $$\frac{6x^4+4x^2}{x}=6x^3+4x$$ when $x\neq 0.$

Comment: Also, $x$ and $x+1$ have the same derivative, but are different functions. Not relevant for this example, however.

Comment: Use the quotient rule to see that the derivatives are not the same.

Comment: $x^2$ and $x^2+5$ have the same derivative, $2x$ and the same domain.  They are different functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming these are functions of a real variable and their domains are presumed to be the largest subsets of reals for which the functions are defined, the answer is: **they actually do NOT have the same derivatives, because these derivatives have different domains (just as the original functions do)**.

In (2), the domains for both the function and its derivative is $\mathbb{R}$.

In (1), the domains for both the function and its derivative is $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$; note that it's the domain for the derivative because the derivative of a function wouldn't make any sense at the points where the original function isn't defined.

Answer (score 1):

They are different functions, but there's only one reason for that: they have a different domain. One has the domain $\mathbb R$, while for the other it's $\mathbb R\backslash \{0\}$. But at all points where their domains overlap, they have the same value. So it shouldn't come as a surprise that their derivatives are the same where their domains overlap. The only difference between the derivative functions: they also have different domains. A derivative function can't have a larger domain than the function it's a derivative of!So to be precise, their derivatives are also not the ssame. One has domain $\mathbb R$, the other $\mathbb R\backslash\{0\}$. And they, too, have the same values where their domains overlap. But that's not enough for to two functions to be equal. Functions are only equal if their domains *and* the values they have are the same (and there codomains are equal, but that point is usually left out in lower level classes).